# Reverse engineering. How to see the code executed before the breakpoint

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, lldb, arm64, disassembly

Once in a game I was playing, a smart person wrote a cheat that allows you to disconnect all players from the server. I became interested in how it is possible to create protection against this. The situation was aggravated by the fact that the person who created the cheat distributed it to other players and disconnecting from the server became a regular event.

I got the source code of this cheat, I will show a fragment with a "connection switch":

[image]

[image]

I figured out how the cheat works. In the LLDB debugger, I found the Disconnect() function, it is called just when the "cheater" uses the cheat. In the disassembler, I decided to just remove Disconnect (), of course this is stupid, because I violated the logic of the game because of which I could not play. As a result of something, this function was called for me, I need to find out what code was executed before the breakpoint with Disconnect ()

Answer (score 0):

Well its hard to tell, but my suggestion is you add some Debug.Log prints in certain scripts you think could be called before the disconnection happens, I know this sounds like a tedious work but you probably have some scripts you think could be called before. Else I would search for some keyword like "kickall" and be sure to set "all files in project" option so that it shows all possible candidates. I hope this serves you